# How do I access an attribute in an event handler?

Tags: jquery

Why does the following code produce two different alerts? I'm trying to add the "myAttr" attribute using Jquery, but it's value is not available inside the live click handler.

```
$("#holder").append("<div class='varInfo' myAttr='1'>new</div>")
    .attr("myAttr","a1")
    .click(function(){
        alert($(this).attr("myAttr"));
    });

$(".varInfo").live('click',function(){
    alert($(this).attr("myAttr"));
});
```

Comment: thats because you are adding the attribute after the append to the #holder element, unless thats is what you want to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because in the first code block, you are setting the "myAttr" attribute on #holder, not on div.varInfo. You are also seeting the click handler on #holder. You need to append .varInfo, and then find it.

```
$("#holder").append("<div class='varInfo' myAttr='1'>new</div>")
    .find('.varInfo')
    .attr("myAttr","a1")
    .click(function(){
        alert($(this).attr("myAttr"));
    });

$(".varInfo").live('click',function(){
    alert($(this).attr("myAttr"));
});
```

I'd actually recommend switching it up a bit like this if you can:

```
$('<div class="varInfo" myAttr="1">new</div>')
    .attr('myAttr', 'a1')
    .click( function() {
        alert( $(this).attr('myAttr') );
    })
    .appendTo('#holder');

$(".varInfo").live('click',function(){
    alert($(this).attr("myAttr"));
});
```